# Display only filtered items JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase

My app displays all items using pagination by 8 elements, and creates them dynamically in JavaScript. It has a filter which should display only specific items by fields filtered. When I use the filter, I get the correct items but it adds to the others already displayed instead of just showing those filtered.

For example, when I go to main page I see first 8 posts, I use the filter which satisfy condition for only one item, and I get 9 posts in the page instead of that 1. I am not sure how to proceed in such situation, I believe that we have to delete default items and then display the filtered data instead, which does not sound effective.
Here is the method to display all elements

```
const getPosts = async () => {
  let postsReference = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .orderBy("createdAt")
    .limit(8);

  await postsReference.get().then((snapshot) => {
    docs = snapshot;
    lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  });
  docs["docs"].forEach((doc) => {
    postsArray.push(doc.data());
  });

  postsArray.forEach((post) => {
    // create item displayed
    createPost(post);
  });
};
```

Here I have the filter data method

```
applyFilterButton.addEventListener("click", async = () => {
  let docs;
  let filteredPostsArray = [];
  let filterQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", productTypeOption)
    .where("type", "==", gameTypeOption)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
    docs = querySnapshot;

    docs["docs"].forEach((doc) => {
      filteredPostsArray.push(doc.data());
    });

    filteredPostsArray.forEach((post) => {
      createPost(post);
    });
  filterPopup.style.display = "none";
});
```

I understand that this is the expected behavior since the methods are the same and I just add elements but I am wondering what should be done in such situation to achieve what I want?

Comment: If list of products isn't very large just download everything and apply filter to downloaded data, so you don't have to make a web request every time you apply filter

Comment: where is `productTypeOption` defined

Comment: If your data-set has 10000 entries and you paginate by 8, then when you apply filters you could have a result of e.g. 3000 entries. Which should be shown as pages of 8 posts per page.Since you populate data by applying limit to the firebase query then you should also apply the same logic to the filtering function. So to sum up i think you need something like `.orderBy("createdAt").limit(8)` in the query of the filtering function also.

Comment: I think that you correctly believe remove already existing posts and it is effective because you are removing 8 posts only. I don't think your app does a lot of time to create 8 new ones since that would not be very effective to my opinion. Bottom line your initial though is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is behaving as it should. You initially call `getPosts` which adds 8 posts to the page.

```
const getPosts = async () => {
  let postsReference = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .orderBy("createdAt")
    .limit(8);

  await postsReference.get().then((snapshot) => {
    docs = snapshot;
    lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  });
  docs["docs"].forEach((doc) => {
    postsArray.push(doc.data());
  });

  postsArray.forEach((post) => {
    // create item displayed
    createPost(post);
  });
};
```

When you click the button for filtering posts, you simply add more posts to the ones that already exist.

```
applyFilterButton.addEventListener("click", async = () => {
  let docs;
  let filteredPostsArray = [];
  let filterQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", productTypeOption)
    .where("type", "==", gameTypeOption)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
    docs = querySnapshot;

    docs["docs"].forEach((doc) => {
      filteredPostsArray.push(doc.data());
    });

    filteredPostsArray.forEach((post) => {
      createPost(post);
    });
  filterPopup.style.display = "none";
});
```

What you basically need is one more method that will erase the posts that exist there in the first place. So you have to make `removePosts` method. I assume that you could do that by some explicit `class` that those posts have as `HTML` elements.
After that you will have to execute this inside your `click` handler.

```
applyFilterButton.addEventListener("click", async = () => {
  removePosts();
  let docs;
  let filteredPostsArray = [];
  let filterQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", productTypeOption)
    .where("type", "==", gameTypeOption)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
    docs = querySnapshot;

    docs["docs"].forEach((doc) => {
      filteredPostsArray.push(doc.data());
    });

    filteredPostsArray.forEach((post) => {
      createPost(post);
    });
  filterPopup.style.display = "none";
});
```